# Aligning to the bottom in flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have containers that should change height dynamically depending on the content.  For all containers in a given row, the bottom text should all be fixed to the bottom regardless of content in each one's container.

```css
.flex-list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.flex-list .flex-row {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.flex-list .flex-row .flex-item-wrapper {
  margin-right: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
}
.flex-list .flex-row .flex-item-wrapper:last-child {
  margin-right: 0px;
  background-color: transparent;
}
.flex-list .flex-row .flex-item-wrapper .flex-item {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.flex-item-stats {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  color: grey;
  padding-top: 10px;
}
.flex-item-stats > * {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
.caption {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="profile-content flex-list">
  <div class="flex-row">
    <div class="flex-item-wrapper">
      <div class="flex-item thumbnail clickable" data-href="#">
        <img class="img-circle" src="http://blog.blogcatalog.com/wp-content/uploads/mario-300x300.jpg" style="width:150px">
        <div class="caption">
          <h4>
                <a href="#">Y-find</a>
              </h4>
          <div class="flex-item-stats">
            <small>left</small>
            <small>right</small>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item-wrapper">
      <div class="flex-item thumbnail clickable" data-href="#">
        <img class="img-circle" src="http://blog.blogcatalog.com/wp-content/uploads/mario-300x300.jpg" style="width:150px">
        <div class="caption">
          <h4>
                <a href="#">Cardguard Namfix</a>
              </h4>
          <div class="flex-item-stats">
            <small>left</small>
            <small>right</small>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item-wrapper">
      <div class="flex-item thumbnail clickable" data-href="#">
        <img class="img-circle" src="http://blog.blogcatalog.com/wp-content/uploads/mario-300x300.jpg" style="width:150px">
        <div class="caption">
          <h4>
                <a href="#">Voyatouch Voyatouch Voyatouch Voyatouch Voyatouch Voyatouch </a>
              </h4>
          <div class="flex-item-stats">
            <small>left</small>
            <small>right</small>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item-wrapper">
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

I thought using `display:flex` on `.caption` along with `space-between` would work to push `flex-item-stats` to the bottom but it doesn't seem to be doing anything.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qkf1yjLb/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Align an element to bottom with flexbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31000885/align-an-element-to-bottom-with-flexbox)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to make the parent a flex container:

```
.flex-list .flex-row .flex-item-wrapper .flex-item {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;                      /* new */
    flex-direction: column;             /* new */
}
```

Then, tell the `.caption` element to fill available height:

```
.caption { flex: 1; }
```

[Revised Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qkf1yjLb/4/)

It's a common question. Here are other options:

- [Methods for Aligning Flex Items](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33856609/3597276)
- [Flexbox align to bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35866238/3597276)
- [Pin a flex item to the bottom of the container](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45555815/3597276)
- [Pin element (flex item) to bottom of container](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33114716/3597276)
- [Pin element to the bottom of the container](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42137339/3597276)
- [Pin a button to the bottom corner of a container](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45603237/3597276)
- [Aligning element to bottom with flexbox](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48218246/3597276)
- [Aligning items to the bottom using flex](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35440234/3597276)
- [Align content of flex items to bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38125562/3597276)
- [Align content in a flex container to the bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40618012/3597276)
- [Aligning element to bottom with flexbox](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48218246/3597276)
- [Nested flexbox, align-items do not flex-end](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36899952/3597276)
- [align-content: flex-end not shifting elements to container bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37913807/3597276)
- [Sticky footer with flexbox](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50429737/3597276)
- [Why isn't align-self aligning my div to the bottom of my flexbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35020265/3597276)
- [How to bottom-align an element inside a flex item?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44950502/3597276)
- [Flexbox difficulties aligning icons to bottom of container](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33216604/3597276)
- [Make an item stick to the bottom using flex in react-native](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38887069/3597276)
- [Equal height columns and align last item to bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36873419/3597276)

Answer (score 1):

If you change your `.caption` code to:

```
.caption {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

and then add:

```
.flex-item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```