# How to keep a component from moving upwards with a growing view

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm trying to create a messenger with react native and I have one problem that I can't seem to fix.  Here is how it looks so far, I have the send button (a button component from React Native Elements) next to an input that is the same view as the button, as shown here:

[image]

Here the button is placed properly next to the input.  However whenever the input and the view grow because multiple lines are being typed, the button moves up with them:

[image]

How do I keep the button at all times in the same position that it was in whenever the input was only a single line?

Here is my code:

```
<KeyboardAvoidingView style={styles.container} 
behavior="padding"
keyboardVerticalOffset={64}>
    <View>
        <FlatList
        //...
        />
    <View 
        minHeight={45}
        style={{flexDirection:'row', backgroundColor: 'transparent' }}>
        <TextInput
            style={[styles.textInput, {fontSize:17,marginVertical: 0, width:300, marginLeft: 10}]}
            minHeight={25}
            multiline={true}
            enablesReturnKeyAutomatically={true}
            keyboardAppearance="dark"
            placeholder=""
            onChangeText={(message) => {this.setState({message})}}
            value={this.state.message}
        />
        <Button
             buttonStyle={{borderRadius: 25, bottom:-5, marginLeft: 10, paddingVertical: 5, backgroundColor: "#EAB844"}}
             icon={{name: 'arrow-up', type: 'feather', color:'white'}}
             onPress={()=>{ this.onPressButton()}} 
             title=""/> 
         </View>
    </View>
</KeyboardAvoidingView>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this would be similar to this?

In React Native, the default value of `flexDirection` is `column` (unlike in CSS, where it is `row`).
Hence, in `flexDirection: 'column'` the cross-axis is horizontal and `alignSelf` works left/right.
To pin your footer to the bottom, there are several options. Here's one:
apply `justifyContent: 'space-between'` to the container.  I've also seen things that use `justifyContent: 'flex-end'`.

from this question - there are other solutions there as well if that one doesn't work.
[Make an item stick to the bottom using flex in react-native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38887069/make-an-item-stick-to-the-bottom-using-flex-in-react-native)

Comment: It didn't, I had to wrap the input and buttons in separate views within another separate view from the one with the flatlist, and then have both the button view and input view grow with an increasing text input.  I then used marginBottom to make the button stay in position.