# Pin a button to the bottom corner of a container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am using flexbox to center a form vertically and horizontally. Inside this form I'd like to pin a button to the bottom right of the flexbox container. I am not sure how to get the button pinned to the bottom right though.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

form {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 1em;
}

.form-button {
  margin-top: 1em;
  align-self: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <form>
    <div class="form-input">
      <label> Name <input type="text" /></label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-button">
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to make the `form` element a flex container, because flex properties only work between parent and child elements.

In other words, your `align-self: flex-end` on the `.form-button` is not working because the parent – `form` – does not have `display: flex` or `display: inline-flex` applied.

Here's a more complete explanation:

- [Proper use of flex properties when nesting flex containers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37840646/3597276)

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

form {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 1em;

  /* NEW */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.form-button {
  margin-top: 1em;
  align-self: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <form>
    <div class="form-input">
      <label> Name <input type="text" /></label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-button">
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
   </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: I see! I needed to make the form a flex container as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
.form-button {
  margin-top: 1em;
  align-self: flex-end;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*Just insert `float: right;`*

*like this:*

```
.form-button {
  float: right;<-----------added
  //more code...
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

form {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 1em;
}

.form-button {
  margin-top: 1em;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <form>
    <div class="form-input">
      <label> Name <input type="text" /></label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-button">
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```