# Aligning element to bottom with flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to align a DIV to the bottom with flexbox using `align-content: flex-end` (and trying `align-self:  flex-end`) with no luck.

What am I doing wrong here? I thought `align-content` aligned... well.. the content to whatever the height/width allowed.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

div.slots {
  background: white;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 250px;
  align-content: flex-end;
}
div.slots div.top_slots {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 25% 50% 25%;
}
div.slots div.bottom_slots {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 25% 25% 25% 25%;
}
div.slots div.slot {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #676767;
  height: 35px;
}
div.slots div.slot svg {
  fill: #272727;
}
div.slots div.slot:hover {
  background-color: #8d8d8d;
}
div.slots div.pane {
  background: grey;
  height: 100px;
  width: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="slots">
  <div class="top_slots">
    <div class="slot stats">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" height="24"><path class="heroicon-ui" d="M20 22H4a2 2 0 0 1-2-2v-8c0-1.1.9-2 2-2h4V8c0-1.1.9-2 2-2h4V4c0-1.1.9-2 2-2h4a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v16a2 2 0 0 1-2 2zM14 8h-4v12h4V8zm-6 4H4v8h4v-8zm8-8v16h4V4h-4z"/></svg>
    </div>
    <div class="inventory slot">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" height="24"><path class="heroicon-ui" d="M8 7V5c0-1.1.9-2 2-2h4a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v2h4a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v10a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H4a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V9c0-1.1.9-2 2-2h4zm8 2H8v10h8V9zm2 0v10h2V9h-2zM6 9H4v10h2V9zm4-2h4V5h-4v2z"/></svg>
    </div>
    <div class="wear slot">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" height="24"><path class="heroicon-ui" d="M12 12a5 5 0 1 1 0-10 5 5 0 0 1 0 10zm0-2a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm9 11a1 1 0 0 1-2 0v-2a3 3 0 0 0-3-3H8a3 3 0 0 0-3 3v2a1 1 0 0 1-2 0v-2a5 5 0 0 1 5-5h8a5 5 0 0 1 5 5v2z"/></svg>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="pane">
    Stuff goes here
  </div>

  <div class="bottom_slots">
    <div class="slot friends_list">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" height="24"><path class="heroicon-ui" d="M12 22a10 10 0 1 1 0-20 10 10 0 0 1 0 20zm0-2a8 8 0 1 0 0-16 8 8 0 0 0 0 16zm-3.54-4.46a1 1 0 0 1 1.42-1.42 3 3 0 0 0 4.24 0 1 1 0 0 1 1.42 1.42 5 5 0 0 1-7.08 0zM9 11a1 1 0 1 1 0-2 1 1 0 0 1 0 2zm6 0a1 1 0 1 1 0-2 1 1 0 0 1 0 2z"/></svg>
    </div>
    <div class="slot settings">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" height="24"><path class="heroicon-ui" d="M9 4.58V4c0-1.1.9-2 2-2h2a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v.58a8 8 0 0 1 1.92 1.11l.5-.29a2 2 0 0 1 2.74.73l1 1.74a2 2 0 0 1-.73 2.73l-.5.29a8.06 8.06 0 0 1 0 2.22l.5.3a2 2 0 0 1 .73 2.72l-1 1.74a2 2 0 0 1-2.73.73l-.5-.3A8 8 0 0 1 15 19.43V20a2 2 0 0 1-2 2h-2a2 2 0 0 1-2-2v-.58a8 8 0 0 1-1.92-1.11l-.5.29a2 2 0 0 1-2.74-.73l-1-1.74a2 2 0 0 1 .73-2.73l.5-.29a8.06 8.06 0 0 1 0-2.22l-.5-.3a2 2 0 0 1-.73-2.72l1-1.74a2 2 0 0 1 2.73-.73l.5.3A8 8 0 0 1 9 4.57zM7.88 7.64l-.54.51-1.77-1.02-1 1.74 1.76 1.01-.17.73a6.02 6.02 0 0 0 0 2.78l.17.73-1.76 1.01 1 1.74 1.77-1.02.54.51a6 6 0 0 0 2.4 1.4l.72.2V20h2v-2.04l.71-.2a6 6 0 0 0 2.41-1.4l.54-.51 1.77 1.02 1-1.74-1.76-1.01.17-.73a6.02 6.02 0 0 0 0-2.78l-.17-.73 1.76-1.01-1-1.74-1.77 1.02-.54-.51a6 6 0 0 0-2.4-1.4l-.72-.2V4h-2v2.04l-.71.2a6 6 0 0 0-2.41 1.4zM12 16a4 4 0 1 1 0-8 4 4 0 0 1 0 8zm0-2a2 2 0 1 0 0-4 2 2 0 0 0 0 4z"/></svg>
    </div>
    <div class="slot logout">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" height="24"><path class="heroicon-ui" d="M5 3h14a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v14a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H5a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V5c0-1.1.9-2 2-2zm0 2v14h14V5H5zm11 7a1 1 0 0 1-1 1H9a1 1 0 0 1 0-2h6a1 1 0 0 1 1 1z"/></svg>
    </div>
    <div class="slot quests">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" height="24"><path class="heroicon-ui" d="M19 10v6a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v2a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H5a2 2 0 0 1-2-2v-2c0-1.1.9-2 2-2v-6a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V7a1 1 0 0 1 .55-.9l8-4a1 1 0 0 1 .9 0l8 4A1 1 0 0 1 21 7v1a2 2 0 0 1-2 2zm-6 0h-2v6h2v-6zm4 0h-2v6h2v-6zm-8 0H7v6h2v-6zM5 7.62V8h14v-.38l-7-3.5-7 3.5zM5 18v2h14v-2H5z"/></svg>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is what I see, exactly what you would like to change? http://prntscr.com/hz9dko

The bottom slots are indeed at the bottom

Comment: @NicolasM.Pardo Maybe I didn't explain myself. I want the whole grey box aligned to the bottom. Including the top small boxes, the pane in the middle and the bottom small boxes (as a group) thank you.

Comment: @nn2 aligned to the bottom of what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now, `.slots` is a flex container containing flex items. One way to align it with the bottom by using flexbox is by putting it in another flexbox container. This can be visualized by asking the question: "align it to the bottom of what?" The answer is: "to the bottom of another flex container".

So, in addition to being a flex *container*, `.slots` can also be a flex *item* inside another flex container. Then you can align `.slots` with the bottom of *its* container.

Below, I've set it's container `<body>` to be a flex container for the `.slots` element. This is similar to one of the methods for a ["sticky footer", detailed at CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/couple-takes-sticky-footer/#article-header-id-3).

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}


/* ADDED THIS */
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

div.slots {
  background: white;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 250px;
  /* align-content: flex-end; - NOT NEEDED */
}

div.slots div.top_slots {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 25% 50% 25%;
}

div.slots div.bottom_slots {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 25% 25% 25% 25%;
}

div.slots div.slot {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #676767;
  height: 35px;
}

div.slots div.slot svg {
  fill: #272727;
}

div.slots div.slot:hover {
  background-color: #8d8d8d;
}

div.slots div.pane {
  background: grey;
  height: 100px;
  width: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="slots">
  <div class="top_slots">
    <div class="slot stats">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" height="24"><path class="heroicon-ui" d="M20 22H4a2 2 0 0 1-2-2v-8c0-1.1.9-2 2-2h4V8c0-1.1.9-2 2-2h4V4c0-1.1.9-2 2-2h4a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v16a2 2 0 0 1-2 2zM14 8h-4v12h4V8zm-6 4H4v8h4v-8zm8-8v16h4V4h-4z"/></svg>
    </div>
    <div class="inventory slot">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" height="24"><path class="heroicon-ui" d="M8 7V5c0-1.1.9-2 2-2h4a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v2h4a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v10a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H4a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V9c0-1.1.9-2 2-2h4zm8 2H8v10h8V9zm2 0v10h2V9h-2zM6 9H4v10h2V9zm4-2h4V5h-4v2z"/></svg>
    </div>
    <div class="wear slot">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" height="24"><path class="heroicon-ui" d="M12 12a5 5 0 1 1 0-10 5 5 0 0 1 0 10zm0-2a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm9 11a1 1 0 0 1-2 0v-2a3 3 0 0 0-3-3H8a3 3 0 0 0-3 3v2a1 1 0 0 1-2 0v-2a5 5 0 0 1 5-5h8a5 5 0 0 1 5 5v2z"/></svg>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="pane">
    Stuff goes here
  </div>

  <div class="bottom_slots">
    <div class="slot friends_list">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" height="24"><path class="heroicon-ui" d="M12 22a10 10 0 1 1 0-20 10 10 0 0 1 0 20zm0-2a8 8 0 1 0 0-16 8 8 0 0 0 0 16zm-3.54-4.46a1 1 0 0 1 1.42-1.42 3 3 0 0 0 4.24 0 1 1 0 0 1 1.42 1.42 5 5 0 0 1-7.08 0zM9 11a1 1 0 1 1 0-2 1 1 0 0 1 0 2zm6 0a1 1 0 1 1 0-2 1 1 0 0 1 0 2z"/></svg>
    </div>
    <div class="slot settings">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" height="24"><path class="heroicon-ui" d="M9 4.58V4c0-1.1.9-2 2-2h2a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v.58a8 8 0 0 1 1.92 1.11l.5-.29a2 2 0 0 1 2.74.73l1 1.74a2 2 0 0 1-.73 2.73l-.5.29a8.06 8.06 0 0 1 0 2.22l.5.3a2 2 0 0 1 .73 2.72l-1 1.74a2 2 0 0 1-2.73.73l-.5-.3A8 8 0 0 1 15 19.43V20a2 2 0 0 1-2 2h-2a2 2 0 0 1-2-2v-.58a8 8 0 0 1-1.92-1.11l-.5.29a2 2 0 0 1-2.74-.73l-1-1.74a2 2 0 0 1 .73-2.73l.5-.29a8.06 8.06 0 0 1 0-2.22l-.5-.3a2 2 0 0 1-.73-2.72l1-1.74a2 2 0 0 1 2.73-.73l.5.3A8 8 0 0 1 9 4.57zM7.88 7.64l-.54.51-1.77-1.02-1 1.74 1.76 1.01-.17.73a6.02 6.02 0 0 0 0 2.78l.17.73-1.76 1.01 1 1.74 1.77-1.02.54.51a6 6 0 0 0 2.4 1.4l.72.2V20h2v-2.04l.71-.2a6 6 0 0 0 2.41-1.4l.54-.51 1.77 1.02 1-1.74-1.76-1.01.17-.73a6.02 6.02 0 0 0 0-2.78l-.17-.73 1.76-1.01-1-1.74-1.77 1.02-.54-.51a6 6 0 0 0-2.4-1.4l-.72-.2V4h-2v2.04l-.71.2a6 6 0 0 0-2.41 1.4zM12 16a4 4 0 1 1 0-8 4 4 0 0 1 0 8zm0-2a2 2 0 1 0 0-4 2 2 0 0 0 0 4z"/></svg>
    </div>
    <div class="slot logout">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" height="24"><path class="heroicon-ui" d="M5 3h14a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v14a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H5a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V5c0-1.1.9-2 2-2zm0 2v14h14V5H5zm11 7a1 1 0 0 1-1 1H9a1 1 0 0 1 0-2h6a1 1 0 0 1 1 1z"/></svg>
    </div>
    <div class="slot quests">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" height="24"><path class="heroicon-ui" d="M19 10v6a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v2a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H5a2 2 0 0 1-2-2v-2c0-1.1.9-2 2-2v-6a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V7a1 1 0 0 1 .55-.9l8-4a1 1 0 0 1 .9 0l8 4A1 1 0 0 1 21 7v1a2 2 0 0 1-2 2zm-6 0h-2v6h2v-6zm4 0h-2v6h2v-6zm-8 0H7v6h2v-6zM5 7.62V8h14v-.38l-7-3.5-7 3.5zM5 18v2h14v-2H5z"/></svg>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

[Michael_B's Scenario #2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48218246/aligning-element-to-bottom-with-flexbox#answer-48218380) might be a more efficient solution (fewer containers). It positions all the flex items at the bottom of `.slots`, which extends the full height of the page by way of `height:100vh`.

I'd say the decision is partly based on what else exists on the page.

Comment: I've meaning to learn CSS Grid so this is a welcome change. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

### Scenario 1

The `align-content` property, as well as `align-items` and `align-self`, work only on the cross axis of a flex container.

In a container with `flex-direction: column`, the main axis is vertical and the cross axis is horizontal. That means that the `align-*` properties shift items left/right, not top/bottom.

So `align-content` will not bottom-align a flex item in a column-direction container.

The next issue to consider is that a flex item and its content are not one element. They represent two elements. So to align the content of your flex item, use a nested flex container.

```css
div.slots {
  background: white;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 250px;
  height: 100vh;
}

div.slots div.top_slots {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 25% 50% 25%;
}

div.slots div.bottom_slots {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 25% 25% 25% 25%;
}

div.slots div.slot {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #676767;
  height: 35px;
}

div.slots div.slot svg {
  fill: #272727;
}

div.slots div.slot:hover {
  background-color: #8d8d8d;
}

div.slots div.pane {
  background: grey;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  
  /****** NEW ******/
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="slots">
  <div class="top_slots">
    <div class="slot stats">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" height="24">
        <path class="heroicon-ui" d="M20 22H4a2 2 0 0 1-2-2v-8c0-1.1.9-2 2-2h4V8c0-1.1.9-2 2-2h4V4c0-1.1.9-2 2-2h4a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v16a2 2 0 0 1-2 2zM14 8h-4v12h4V8zm-6 4H4v8h4v-8zm8-8v16h4V4h-4z" />
      </svg>
    </div>
    <div class="inventory slot">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" height="24">
        <path class="heroicon-ui" d="M8 7V5c0-1.1.9-2 2-2h4a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v2h4a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v10a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H4a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V9c0-1.1.9-2 2-2h4zm8 2H8v10h8V9zm2 0v10h2V9h-2zM6 9H4v10h2V9zm4-2h4V5h-4v2z" />
      </svg>
    </div>
    <div class="wear slot">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" height="24">
        <path class="heroicon-ui" d="M12 12a5 5 0 1 1 0-10 5 5 0 0 1 0 10zm0-2a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm9 11a1 1 0 0 1-2 0v-2a3 3 0 0 0-3-3H8a3 3 0 0 0-3 3v2a1 1 0 0 1-2 0v-2a5 5 0 0 1 5-5h8a5 5 0 0 1 5 5v2z" />
      </svg>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="pane">
    Stuff goes here
  </div>

  <div class="bottom_slots">
    <div class="slot friends_list">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" height="24">
        <path class="heroicon-ui" d="M12 22a10 10 0 1 1 0-20 10 10 0 0 1 0 20zm0-2a8 8 0 1 0 0-16 8 8 0 0 0 0 16zm-3.54-4.46a1 1 0 0 1 1.42-1.42 3 3 0 0 0 4.24 0 1 1 0 0 1 1.42 1.42 5 5 0 0 1-7.08 0zM9 11a1 1 0 1 1 0-2 1 1 0 0 1 0 2zm6 0a1 1 0 1 1 0-2 1 1 0 0 1 0 2z"
        />
      </svg>
    </div>
    <div class="slot settings">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" height="24">
        <path class="heroicon-ui" d="M9 4.58V4c0-1.1.9-2 2-2h2a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v.58a8 8 0 0 1 1.92 1.11l.5-.29a2 2 0 0 1 2.74.73l1 1.74a2 2 0 0 1-.73 2.73l-.5.29a8.06 8.06 0 0 1 0 2.22l.5.3a2 2 0 0 1 .73 2.72l-1 1.74a2 2 0 0 1-2.73.73l-.5-.3A8 8 0 0 1 15 19.43V20a2 2 0 0 1-2 2h-2a2 2 0 0 1-2-2v-.58a8 8 0 0 1-1.92-1.11l-.5.29a2 2 0 0 1-2.74-.73l-1-1.74a2 2 0 0 1 .73-2.73l.5-.29a8.06 8.06 0 0 1 0-2.22l-.5-.3a2 2 0 0 1-.73-2.72l1-1.74a2 2 0 0 1 2.73-.73l.5.3A8 8 0 0 1 9 4.57zM7.88 7.64l-.54.51-1.77-1.02-1 1.74 1.76 1.01-.17.73a6.02 6.02 0 0 0 0 2.78l.17.73-1.76 1.01 1 1.74 1.77-1.02.54.51a6 6 0 0 0 2.4 1.4l.72.2V20h2v-2.04l.71-.2a6 6 0 0 0 2.41-1.4l.54-.51 1.77 1.02 1-1.74-1.76-1.01.17-.73a6.02 6.02 0 0 0 0-2.78l-.17-.73 1.76-1.01-1-1.74-1.77 1.02-.54-.51a6 6 0 0 0-2.4-1.4l-.72-.2V4h-2v2.04l-.71.2a6 6 0 0 0-2.41 1.4zM12 16a4 4 0 1 1 0-8 4 4 0 0 1 0 8zm0-2a2 2 0 1 0 0-4 2 2 0 0 0 0 4z"
        />
      </svg>
    </div>
    <div class="slot logout">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" height="24">
        <path class="heroicon-ui" d="M5 3h14a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v14a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H5a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V5c0-1.1.9-2 2-2zm0 2v14h14V5H5zm11 7a1 1 0 0 1-1 1H9a1 1 0 0 1 0-2h6a1 1 0 0 1 1 1z" />
      </svg>
    </div>
    <div class="slot quests">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" height="24">
        <path class="heroicon-ui" d="M19 10v6a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v2a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H5a2 2 0 0 1-2-2v-2c0-1.1.9-2 2-2v-6a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V7a1 1 0 0 1 .55-.9l8-4a1 1 0 0 1 .9 0l8 4A1 1 0 0 1 21 7v1a2 2 0 0 1-2 2zm-6 0h-2v6h2v-6zm4 0h-2v6h2v-6zm-8 0H7v6h2v-6zM5 7.62V8h14v-.38l-7-3.5-7 3.5zM5 18v2h14v-2H5z"
        />
      </svg>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

### Scenario 2

If the goal is to align the entire element to the bottom, then use `justify-content: flex-end` (main axis), not `align-content: flex-end` (cross axis and multi-line containers only).

```css
div.slots {
  background: white;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;   /* NEW */
  width: 250px;
  height: 100vh;
}

div.slots div.top_slots {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 25% 50% 25%;
}

div.slots div.bottom_slots {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 25% 25% 25% 25%;
}

div.slots div.slot {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #676767;
  height: 35px;
}

div.slots div.slot svg {
  fill: #272727;
}

div.slots div.slot:hover {
  background-color: #8d8d8d;
}

div.slots div.pane {
  background: grey;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  
  
  /****** NEW ******/
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="slots">
  <div class="top_slots">
    <div class="slot stats">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" height="24">
        <path class="heroicon-ui" d="M20 22H4a2 2 0 0 1-2-2v-8c0-1.1.9-2 2-2h4V8c0-1.1.9-2 2-2h4V4c0-1.1.9-2 2-2h4a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v16a2 2 0 0 1-2 2zM14 8h-4v12h4V8zm-6 4H4v8h4v-8zm8-8v16h4V4h-4z" />
      </svg>
    </div>
    <div class="inventory slot">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" height="24">
        <path class="heroicon-ui" d="M8 7V5c0-1.1.9-2 2-2h4a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v2h4a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v10a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H4a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V9c0-1.1.9-2 2-2h4zm8 2H8v10h8V9zm2 0v10h2V9h-2zM6 9H4v10h2V9zm4-2h4V5h-4v2z" />
      </svg>
    </div>
    <div class="wear slot">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" height="24">
        <path class="heroicon-ui" d="M12 12a5 5 0 1 1 0-10 5 5 0 0 1 0 10zm0-2a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm9 11a1 1 0 0 1-2 0v-2a3 3 0 0 0-3-3H8a3 3 0 0 0-3 3v2a1 1 0 0 1-2 0v-2a5 5 0 0 1 5-5h8a5 5 0 0 1 5 5v2z" />
      </svg>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="pane">
    Stuff goes here
  </div>

  <div class="bottom_slots">
    <div class="slot friends_list">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" height="24">
        <path class="heroicon-ui" d="M12 22a10 10 0 1 1 0-20 10 10 0 0 1 0 20zm0-2a8 8 0 1 0 0-16 8 8 0 0 0 0 16zm-3.54-4.46a1 1 0 0 1 1.42-1.42 3 3 0 0 0 4.24 0 1 1 0 0 1 1.42 1.42 5 5 0 0 1-7.08 0zM9 11a1 1 0 1 1 0-2 1 1 0 0 1 0 2zm6 0a1 1 0 1 1 0-2 1 1 0 0 1 0 2z"
        />
      </svg>
    </div>
    <div class="slot settings">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" height="24">
        <path class="heroicon-ui" d="M9 4.58V4c0-1.1.9-2 2-2h2a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v.58a8 8 0 0 1 1.92 1.11l.5-.29a2 2 0 0 1 2.74.73l1 1.74a2 2 0 0 1-.73 2.73l-.5.29a8.06 8.06 0 0 1 0 2.22l.5.3a2 2 0 0 1 .73 2.72l-1 1.74a2 2 0 0 1-2.73.73l-.5-.3A8 8 0 0 1 15 19.43V20a2 2 0 0 1-2 2h-2a2 2 0 0 1-2-2v-.58a8 8 0 0 1-1.92-1.11l-.5.29a2 2 0 0 1-2.74-.73l-1-1.74a2 2 0 0 1 .73-2.73l.5-.29a8.06 8.06 0 0 1 0-2.22l-.5-.3a2 2 0 0 1-.73-2.72l1-1.74a2 2 0 0 1 2.73-.73l.5.3A8 8 0 0 1 9 4.57zM7.88 7.64l-.54.51-1.77-1.02-1 1.74 1.76 1.01-.17.73a6.02 6.02 0 0 0 0 2.78l.17.73-1.76 1.01 1 1.74 1.77-1.02.54.51a6 6 0 0 0 2.4 1.4l.72.2V20h2v-2.04l.71-.2a6 6 0 0 0 2.41-1.4l.54-.51 1.77 1.02 1-1.74-1.76-1.01.17-.73a6.02 6.02 0 0 0 0-2.78l-.17-.73 1.76-1.01-1-1.74-1.77 1.02-.54-.51a6 6 0 0 0-2.4-1.4l-.72-.2V4h-2v2.04l-.71.2a6 6 0 0 0-2.41 1.4zM12 16a4 4 0 1 1 0-8 4 4 0 0 1 0 8zm0-2a2 2 0 1 0 0-4 2 2 0 0 0 0 4z"
        />
      </svg>
    </div>
    <div class="slot logout">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" height="24">
        <path class="heroicon-ui" d="M5 3h14a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v14a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H5a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V5c0-1.1.9-2 2-2zm0 2v14h14V5H5zm11 7a1 1 0 0 1-1 1H9a1 1 0 0 1 0-2h6a1 1 0 0 1 1 1z" />
      </svg>
    </div>
    <div class="slot quests">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" height="24">
        <path class="heroicon-ui" d="M19 10v6a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v2a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H5a2 2 0 0 1-2-2v-2c0-1.1.9-2 2-2v-6a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V7a1 1 0 0 1 .55-.9l8-4a1 1 0 0 1 .9 0l8 4A1 1 0 0 1 21 7v1a2 2 0 0 1-2 2zm-6 0h-2v6h2v-6zm4 0h-2v6h2v-6zm-8 0H7v6h2v-6zM5 7.62V8h14v-.38l-7-3.5-7 3.5zM5 18v2h14v-2H5z"
        />
      </svg>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Align-content align items to the cross-axis. Which normally is the vertical one, therefore the "height".

But if you use flex-direction:column the axis switch, so main axis is vertical and cross axis horizontal.

Therefore you mus use justify-content to adjust the vertical alignment of flex items on a flex-direction:column flex-container.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. I tried replacing `align-content: flex-end` with `justify-content: flex-end;` but nothing changed.

Comment: which element are you trying to position, and where do you want to position it?

Answer (score 0):

Add `flex-grow: 1` to the middle element and delete its `height: 100px` to allow it to become higher, and add `margin-top: auto` to the bottom element to move it to the bottom:

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

div.slots {
  background: white;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 250px;
  height: 100vh;
}
div.slots div.top_slots {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 25% 50% 25%;
}
div.slots div.bottom_slots {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 25% 25% 25% 25%;
  margin-top: auto;
}
div.slots div.slot {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #676767;
  height: 35px;
}
div.slots div.slot svg {
  fill: #272727;
}
div.slots div.slot:hover {
  background-color: #8d8d8d;
}
div.slots div.pane {
  background: grey;
  width: auto;
  text-align: center;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="slots">
  <div class="top_slots">
    <div class="slot stats">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" height="24"><path class="heroicon-ui" d="M20 22H4a2 2 0 0 1-2-2v-8c0-1.1.9-2 2-2h4V8c0-1.1.9-2 2-2h4V4c0-1.1.9-2 2-2h4a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v16a2 2 0 0 1-2 2zM14 8h-4v12h4V8zm-6 4H4v8h4v-8zm8-8v16h4V4h-4z"/></svg>
    </div>
    <div class="inventory slot">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" height="24"><path class="heroicon-ui" d="M8 7V5c0-1.1.9-2 2-2h4a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v2h4a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v10a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H4a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V9c0-1.1.9-2 2-2h4zm8 2H8v10h8V9zm2 0v10h2V9h-2zM6 9H4v10h2V9zm4-2h4V5h-4v2z"/></svg>
    </div>
    <div class="wear slot">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" height="24"><path class="heroicon-ui" d="M12 12a5 5 0 1 1 0-10 5 5 0 0 1 0 10zm0-2a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm9 11a1 1 0 0 1-2 0v-2a3 3 0 0 0-3-3H8a3 3 0 0 0-3 3v2a1 1 0 0 1-2 0v-2a5 5 0 0 1 5-5h8a5 5 0 0 1 5 5v2z"/></svg>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="pane">
    Stuff goes here
  </div>

  <div class="bottom_slots">
    <div class="slot friends_list">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" height="24"><path class="heroicon-ui" d="M12 22a10 10 0 1 1 0-20 10 10 0 0 1 0 20zm0-2a8 8 0 1 0 0-16 8 8 0 0 0 0 16zm-3.54-4.46a1 1 0 0 1 1.42-1.42 3 3 0 0 0 4.24 0 1 1 0 0 1 1.42 1.42 5 5 0 0 1-7.08 0zM9 11a1 1 0 1 1 0-2 1 1 0 0 1 0 2zm6 0a1 1 0 1 1 0-2 1 1 0 0 1 0 2z"/></svg>
    </div>
    <div class="slot settings">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" height="24"><path class="heroicon-ui" d="M9 4.58V4c0-1.1.9-2 2-2h2a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v.58a8 8 0 0 1 1.92 1.11l.5-.29a2 2 0 0 1 2.74.73l1 1.74a2 2 0 0 1-.73 2.73l-.5.29a8.06 8.06 0 0 1 0 2.22l.5.3a2 2 0 0 1 .73 2.72l-1 1.74a2 2 0 0 1-2.73.73l-.5-.3A8 8 0 0 1 15 19.43V20a2 2 0 0 1-2 2h-2a2 2 0 0 1-2-2v-.58a8 8 0 0 1-1.92-1.11l-.5.29a2 2 0 0 1-2.74-.73l-1-1.74a2 2 0 0 1 .73-2.73l.5-.29a8.06 8.06 0 0 1 0-2.22l-.5-.3a2 2 0 0 1-.73-2.72l1-1.74a2 2 0 0 1 2.73-.73l.5.3A8 8 0 0 1 9 4.57zM7.88 7.64l-.54.51-1.77-1.02-1 1.74 1.76 1.01-.17.73a6.02 6.02 0 0 0 0 2.78l.17.73-1.76 1.01 1 1.74 1.77-1.02.54.51a6 6 0 0 0 2.4 1.4l.72.2V20h2v-2.04l.71-.2a6 6 0 0 0 2.41-1.4l.54-.51 1.77 1.02 1-1.74-1.76-1.01.17-.73a6.02 6.02 0 0 0 0-2.78l-.17-.73 1.76-1.01-1-1.74-1.77 1.02-.54-.51a6 6 0 0 0-2.4-1.4l-.72-.2V4h-2v2.04l-.71.2a6 6 0 0 0-2.41 1.4zM12 16a4 4 0 1 1 0-8 4 4 0 0 1 0 8zm0-2a2 2 0 1 0 0-4 2 2 0 0 0 0 4z"/></svg>
    </div>
    <div class="slot logout">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" height="24"><path class="heroicon-ui" d="M5 3h14a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v14a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H5a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V5c0-1.1.9-2 2-2zm0 2v14h14V5H5zm11 7a1 1 0 0 1-1 1H9a1 1 0 0 1 0-2h6a1 1 0 0 1 1 1z"/></svg>
    </div>
    <div class="slot quests">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" height="24"><path class="heroicon-ui" d="M19 10v6a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v2a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H5a2 2 0 0 1-2-2v-2c0-1.1.9-2 2-2v-6a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V7a1 1 0 0 1 .55-.9l8-4a1 1 0 0 1 .9 0l8 4A1 1 0 0 1 21 7v1a2 2 0 0 1-2 2zm-6 0h-2v6h2v-6zm4 0h-2v6h2v-6zm-8 0H7v6h2v-6zM5 7.62V8h14v-.38l-7-3.5-7 3.5zM5 18v2h14v-2H5z"/></svg>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```