# Footer Position Fixed overlapping page content

Tags: html, css

I am having issues trying to make my footer at the bottom, but it overlaps the content on the page if there are too much content.

this is my `footer css`

```
footer {
position:fixed;
bottom: 0;
}
```

this is how the page looks without any content
[image: This is how the page looks when no content]

this is how the page looks with overlap content with the footer
[image: this is how the page looks when the content overlaps]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sticky footer with flexbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50429737/sticky-footer-with-flexbox)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could structure your HTML as follows:

```
<body>
  <header class="Header"></header>
  <main class="Main"></main>
  <footer class="Footer"></footer>
</body>
```

Then, use `flex box` to render the footer at the bottom of your page using the following code:

```
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

main {
  flex: 1;
}

footer,
header {
  flex: 0;
}
```

See a fully working demo code below and learn more about flex box [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox):

```css
header::after,
main::after,
footer::after {
  content: attr(class);
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

main {
  flex: 1;
}

footer,
header {
  flex: 0;
}
```

```html
<header class="Header"></header>
<main class="Main"></main>
<footer class="Footer"></footer>
```